# Does Making an AJAX call make a DJANGO form Invalid?

Tags: django, django-forms

I make an ajax call to my server using the change event on a select widget. Does this cause the Django Form to be invalid? Here is an example of the code.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'accountSelections' %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="form-group">
       <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">

                  {{ account_selection_form|crispy }}

              <input class="btn btn-primary" id="button" type="Submit" value="Next >>">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                 &nbsp;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="grid"></div>
              </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>`
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#id_excludeClassification").SumoSelect();

var token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').prop('value');

$( "#id_acctFilterName" ).change(function() {
    var data = "";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : "../filter",
        data : "id="+$(this).val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
        success : function(response) {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                data: response,
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                    field: "acctCd",
                    title: "Code"
                }, {
                    field: "shortName",
                    title: "Account Name"
                }]
            });

            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: response
            });

            grid.dataSource = dataSource;
            dataSource.read();
            grid.refresh();

            data = response;
            return response;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Does a form submit after cause this to make the form invalid?

Comment: Could you add the related code to understand your problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can submit multiple times with the same CSRF token, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you put your `csrfmiddlewaretoken` variable out `data` object that you send to your server then it can't work.

Here is what you have to do :

```js
data : {
    id : $(this).val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
}
```